# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Canvas object must be the same instance that was previously returned by lockCanvas

Tags: java, android

There was another post about the same exception, but the answer to that question was to ensure my `Canvas` is not null first before calling `this.holder.getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(this.canvas)` . In my case, even with `canvas` not null, `SurfaceView` object locked, and the surface created, I still get this exception. Below are two methods which I call 60 times per second from a  `Thread` that runs concurrent with my main thread:

```
public void start_draw_sequence() {
    if (!surface_locked && this.holder.getSurface().isValid()) { // check if not locked already
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            this.canvas = this.holder.getSurface().lockHardwareCanvas();
        } else {
            this.canvas = this.holder.getSurface().lockCanvas(null);
        }
        surface_locked = true;
    }

    if (this.canvas != null) {
        this.canvas.clipRect(0, 0, this.canvas.getWidth(), this.canvas.getHeight());
    }
}

public void end_draw_sequence() {
    if (this.canvas != null && surface_locked && surface_created) {
        this.holder.getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(this.canvas);

        surface_locked = false;
    }
}
```

I first call `start_draw_sequence`, then draw a bunch of bitmaps and such, and when drawing is done i call `end_draw_sequence`. Everything works fine until `Activity.onResume()` is called (after putting the app in the background). The thread is still calling these methods after `onPause()` and `onStop()`.

Why am I getting this exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

If drawing code not in main thread (UI thread) - try to move it to main thread or use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` , to ensure that only one thread at same time could call `lockCanvas()` or `unlockCanvasAndPost()` - I assume that problem happens because some other thread try to lock canvas during another thread already locked it , so if `lockCanvas()` called again, without unlocking previous locked canvas - it return null